# Unresolved dependency: io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.17.1

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j, spring-boot-2

I was referring below tutorial https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring-boot-microservices-circuit-breaker-mohamed-firnas I have added required dependencies but my follwoing import is not working import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.annotation.CircuitBreaker and then in Error Logs we checked this error was coming Unresolved dependency: io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.17.1 . I am not sure why it is not working?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'java'
id 'eclipse'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

ext {
set('springCloudDependencyVersion', "2022.0.4") // 2022.0.4 is the latest one.
set('springCloudAwsVersion',"3.0.4")
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud- dependencies:$springCloudDependencyVersion"
    mavenBom "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:$springCloudAwsVersion"
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
 maven {
    url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'

implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.0.Final'
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudDependencyVersion"
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-dynamodb'
 //resilience4j
implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.17.1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

// annotation processors
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()
 }
```